# How do I maintain 508 compliance in my mobile application using Titanium?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am upgrading an older application written years ago in Titanium.
I want to make it fully 508 compliant. Are there any suggestions, white papers, or tutorials addressing this design issue?

Comment: Asking for documentation/tutorials is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: This question might be off-topic. Consider posting on a different Stack Exchange site, like [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: my apologies if I posed the question improperly. I want to make sure my application is 508 compliant. I have yet to find any documentation on how appcelerator/titanium does this. Maybe I am asking this question in the wrong Stack Exchange? which one would deal with this subject for the Appcelerator studio?